# Why Python returns True for empty space as upper()?

Tags: python, string

Anyone can clarify why the below program returns "J F K" with spaces and not "JFK" ?

```
string = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy"
initials = ""
for letter in string:
    if letter == letter.upper():
        initials += letter
print(initials)
```

On the other hand , the below program returns "JFK" without spaces ,

```
string = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy"
initials = ""
for letter in string:
    if letter != letter.lower():
        initials += letter
print(initials)
```

Thanks!!!

EDIT : Ah ... Do I feel really silly for asking this after reading the answers. I should have tried out the below before asking ...
It returns "ohn itzgerald ennedy"

```
string = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy"
initials = ""
for letter in string:
    if letter == letter.lower():
        initials += letter
print(initials)
```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: `upper()` does not return `True`. It returns an upper case version of the symbol, which you then compare to the original symbol. Space does not have two versions and `.upper()`/`.lower()` on it are no-op. Hence, `space == space.upper()`, moreover, `space == space.lower()` is `True` and `space != space.lower()` is `False`.

Comment: You are checking whether converting the string to upper case returns the same string as the original. For characters which do not _have_ case, this will always be true. It should hardly be surprising; what do you expect `" ".upper()` to return?

Comment: Think about it… what’s the upper case version of a space, and how does it compare to the non-upper case version of a space? And what does each check compare?

Comment: This seems l=ke an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway. It seems that you are    _actually_ trying to figure out whether a character is alphabetic or not. There are already functions for that, but you could in fact check `if letter.upper() == letter.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

Try out `string.upper()`. You'll get `'JOHN FITZGERALD KENNEDY'`. Notice that the uppercase version of a space is unchanged.

If you want to check if a character is upper case, you can use `isupper`:

```
string = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy"
initials = ""
for letter in string:
    if letter.isupper():
        initials += letter
print(initials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because

```py
space(" ") == space(" ").upper() --> True
```

Also

```py
space(" ") != space(" ").upper() --> False
```